# Syntax error passing tuple as parameter values using SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm totally new to Python and SQL but I'm following a tutorial and I really can't get this working. Please ignore the poor string construct but I'll tidy it up when it's working. I'm trying to send two values to insert into a new row on a table, they get passed to it in the cursor execute command.

```py
def update_height(conn, location, timestamp_height):
    sql_update_height_table = """ INSERT INTO """ + str(location) + """_cushion(timestamp,height)
                VALUES(?,?) """
    print (sql_update_height_table)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql_update_height_table,timestamp_height)
    conn.commit()
    return cur.lastrowid
```

Result of `print(sql_update_height_table)`:

```
INSERT INTO 0xEE738a9e_height(timestamp,height)
                VALUES(?,?)
```

and this is the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "0xEE738a9e": syntax error
```

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/insert/) and I really can't see what I'm doing wrong, I've been looking for hours.

`timestamp_height` is a tuple with two entries.

Comment: What is the location? Can you provide an example of the function call ? Also if you can fix your formatting a bit to include all the code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you need to use a table name like this, but `0x` means as usually a HEX representation. Quote the name with backticks.

```py
sql_update_height_table = """ INSERT INTO `""" + str(location) + """_cushion`(timestamp,height)
                VALUES(?,?) """
```

Comment: I'm sure he DOESN'T have a table name that is a hex number.  His problem is the setting of the `location` variable.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. the backticks worked.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was also unsure if he really had such a table name. But apparently you were wrong...

Comment: Wow.  My bad.  Statistically, this was the least likely answer...